# To Do List JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need code of it.

If I remove a `nth-child` (odd/even) list it closes but the next list matches with the color with upper list.

Each list should be different colors(nth child(from even and odd)). That need to be done in javascript.

If a list is already exists with a name, a message("It is already exists.") will appear and it won't add to list.

When I click on a list the text from the clicked list should toggle to between `margin-left: 0;` and `margin-left: 50px;` when unchecked and checked(If you click on a list it will be checked and unchecked).

And which area I should place the code.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#Header {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#myInput {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  outline: none;
}

#Add {
  padding: 18.5px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: ;
  margin-top: ;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#myUL li {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  opacity: 0.9;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

#myUL li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#myUL li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}

#myUL li.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#myUL li.checked:before {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  border-left: 5px solid white;
  border-bottom: 5px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.sp.checkedsp {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.sp {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.close {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #2196f3;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<body>
  <div id="Header">
    <input type="text" placeholder=" Type your text" id="myInput" />
    <span id="Add" onclick="newElement()">Add</span>
  </div>
  <ul id="myUL">
    <li><span class="sp">ASQm<span class="close">&times;</span></span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="sp">ASadQm<span class="close">&times;</span></span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="sp">ASffffQm<span class="close">&times;</span></span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="sp">ASQgeryyyyyyym<span class="close">&times;</span></span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="sp">ASQgvvvvvm<span class="close">&times;</span></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p id="EText"></p>
  <script>
    var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    var A = [];
    var i;
    var ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    var etext = document.getElementById("EText");
    var sp = document.getElementsByClassName("sp");
    var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

    for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
      close[i].onclick = function() {
        this.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "none";
      }
    }

    ul.addEventListener("click", function(n) {
      if (n.target.tagName === "LI") {
        n.target.classList.toggle("checked");
      }
    }, false);

    function newElement() {
      var inputvalue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
      var i;
      var createli = document.createElement("li");

      var span = document.createElement("span");
      span.className = "sp";

      var span2 = document.createElement("span");
      span2.className = "close";

      var closetext = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
      var txt = document.createTextNode(inputvalue);

      if (inputvalue == "") {
        alert("Write something.");
      } else {
        if (A.indexOf(inputvalue) > -1) {
          etext.innerHTML = "already Exists";
        } else {
          var addlist = {
            a: ul.appendChild(createli),
            b: createli.appendChild(span),
            c: span.appendChild(txt),
            d: span.appendChild(span2),
            e: span2.appendChild(closetext)
          }
          A.push(txt);
        }
      }
      input.value = "";

      for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
        close[i].onclick = function() {
          this.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why your items were not getting alternating?**

Because you were hiding the items when an item was closed. You need to remove items instead of hiding them as you are using **even** and **odd** nth child selectors.

**How to add left-margin to text when an item is checked?**

Just by adding this:

```
.checked .sp {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#Header {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#myInput {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  outline: none;
}

#Add {
  padding: 18.5px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: ;
  margin-top: ;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#myUL li {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  opacity: 0.9;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

#myUL li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#myUL li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}

#myUL li.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#myUL li.checked:before {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  border-left: 5px solid white;
  border-bottom: 5px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.sp.checkedsp {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.sp {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.close {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #2196f3;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}

.checked .sp {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<body>
  <div id="Header">
    <input type="text" placeholder=" Type your text" id="myInput" />
    <span id="Add" onclick="newElement()">Add</span>
  </div>
  <ul id="myUL">
    <li><span class="sp">ASQm<span class="close">&times;</span></span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="sp">ASadQm<span class="close">&times;</span></span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="sp">ASffffQm<span class="close">&times;</span></span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="sp">ASQgeryyyyyyym<span class="close">&times;</span></span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="sp">ASQgvvvvvm<span class="close">&times;</span></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p id="EText"></p>
  <script>
    var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    var A = [];
    var i;
    var ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    var etext = document.getElementById("EText");
    var sp = document.getElementsByClassName("sp");
    var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

    for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
      close[i].onclick = function() {
        var parent = this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
        var child = this.parentElement.parentElement;
        parent.removeChild(child);
      }
    }

    ul.addEventListener("click", function(n) {
      if (n.target.tagName === "LI") {
        n.target.classList.toggle("checked");
      }
    }, false);

    function newElement() {
      var inputvalue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
      var i;
      var createli = document.createElement("li");
      
      var span = document.createElement("span");
      span.className = "sp";

      var span2 = document.createElement("span");
      span2.className = "close";

      var closetext = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
      var txt = document.createTextNode(inputvalue);

      if (inputvalue == "") {
        alert("Write something.");
      } else {
        if (A.indexOf(inputvalue) > -1) {
          etext.innerHTML = "already Exists";
        } else {
          var addlist = {
            a: ul.appendChild(createli),
            b: createli.appendChild(span),
            c: span.appendChild(txt),
            d: span.appendChild(span2),
            e: span2.appendChild(closetext)
          }
          A.push(txt);
        }
      }

      input.value = "";

      for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
        close[i].onclick = function() {
          var parent = this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
          var child = this.parentElement.parentElement;
          parent.removeChild(child);
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    A.push(inputvalue);
```

since you check that value if it's in array not text node

Comment: Nothing happens.

Comment: @AL-RAHAT ah, my mistake you don't apped that object to list just change this then. If you compare value if it's in the array, you need to add that value to the array not textNode.